# JPA query with @ManyToOne object

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have these JPA objects:

```
public class BB {

    // ...

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date")
    protected Date date;

    // ...

}

public class B extends BB {

    // ...

    /**
     * The referred a.
     */
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private AA a;

    // ...

}

public class A extends AA {

    // ...

    private String ID;

}
```

Now I want to execute the following query using JPA:

`SELECT * FROM A as a INNER JOIN B as b ON a.ID = b.A_ID ORDER BY b.date`

I tried:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("SELECT a FROM ").
    append(A.class.getSimpleName()).
    append(" a JOIN ").
    append(B.class.getSimpleName()).
    append(" b").
    append(" WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY b.date");

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(builder.toString());

query.getResultList();
```

but it does not work, it gives me a

```
"Encountered \"\" at character 36, but expected: [].\" while parsing JPQL \"SELECT a FROM A a JOIN B b WHERE 1=1\". See nested stack trace for original parse error."
```

error.

Could you please help me with that?
I'm not expert in JPA.

Thanks

Comment: JPQL has many reference documents on the internet. They all will have a section on JOINs. ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on a field, not an entity: try 
    `JOIN a.B b`

if it exists, or write it the other way around if necessary